# How do I sort a GridView column When a header Is clicked?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, sorting

I am following instructions from this MSDN article:
[How to: Sort a GridView Column When a Header Is Clicked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745786.aspx)

But, I'm binding Entity Framework objects to the ListView.

I get a runtime **NotSupportedException** "Specified method is not supported" when the Sort() method fails to execute this line:

```
dataView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
```

How do I need to adapt this example for Entity Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [this](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/08/04/wpf-automatically-sort-a-gridview-continued/) post. It's code written by Thomas Levesque for an attached property that enables the sorting of a GridView by it's column headers. Really well done. 
If it does not fit your needs, you can look on how he implemented its solution.